# SP2013 : Calendar and Meetings - Attendees Issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I'm using SharePoint foundation 2013. 
I need to have a calendar where a reminder mail needs to be sent to attendees who did not respond to the meeting event.

The meeting workspace is missing/deprecated in SP 2013. So what would be the best approach in SP 2013 to maintain attendee's  acceptance (meeting acceptance and related mail responses)?

Greatly appreciate some advise